# boss Fuse trasformation XML usinf XSLT

Tags: java, jboss, jbossfuse

http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 https://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd              http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">

```
<camelContext id="cbr-example-context" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">

    <route id="cbr-route">
        <from id="_from1" uri="file:///d:/inxslt"/>
        <transform.xslt from="_from1" to="_to3" xsltFile="src/main/java/com/xslt/converterXsl.xsl"/>
        <to id="_to3" uri="file:///d:/outxslt"/>


    </route>
</camelContext>
```

> i want to use my converterXsl.xsl format class to transform xml which is in file:///d:/inxslt this path
>   i tried this further here not not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use the following definition of the Camel route.

```
<camelContext id="_context1" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
    <route id="_route1">
        <from id="_from1" uri="file:src/data?noop=true"/>
        <to id="_to1" uri="xslt:file:src/xml2html.xsl"/>
        <to id="_to2" uri="file:target/output"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

Please, adjust file paths to your needs. Especially, notice notation of *XSLT* component.

I hope it helps ;-)

Comment: hi no need to use any java class? this will transform my xml using this xslt ?

Comment: <from id="_from1" uri="file:///d:/inxslt"/>
        <to id="_to1" uri="xslt:file:src/main/java/com/xml/xslt/CourseToStudents.xsl"/>
        <to id="_to2" uri="file:///d:/out"/>

Comment: No java class needed. It should transform your XML file. Do you hit any kind of error? Can you share it?